# How to display data in reverse order using sql query?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have stored the data in the name column as "S B" , I want to display the data as "B S" using SQL query. Another example : "Dan Brown" original data , displayed data "Brown Dan".

The first name and the last name are not stored in separate columns therefore I am not able to understand how to accommodate the spaces. Also I want to make this query generic , so want to add provisions for middle name , if any. 
I have thought of something like : SELECT SUBSTR(  )||" "||(  )...
How do I start reading from the end of the string and accommodate the spacing?

Comment: Is every name exactly two words separated by one space?

Comment: No , there can be a middle name also . Like "Dan Michael Brown". Will be displayed as " Brown Michael Dan".

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the two names using `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(name, '[^ ]+', 1, 1) as first_name,
       regexp_substr(name, '[^ ]+', 1, 2) as second_name
```

You can use these expressions as well in `order by`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I understood the question:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'S B' from dual union all
  3     select 'Dan Brown' from dual union all
  4     select 'Marco van Basten' from dual
  5    )
  6  select col,
  7         listagg(val, ' ') within group (order by rn desc) result
  8  from (select col,
  9               column_value rn,
 10               regexp_substr(col, '[^ ]+', 1, column_value) val
 11        from test cross join
 12             table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 13                                 connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ' ') + 1
 14                                ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 15      )
 16  group by col;

COL              RESULT
---------------- --------------------
Dan Brown        Brown Dan
Marco van Basten Basten van Marco
S B              B S

SQL>
```

What does it do?

- lines #8 - 14 are used to split each name into separate rows
- cross join is with the table function is used to avoid duplicates
- those rows (parts of the names) are aggregated back (with the `listagg` function) in reverse order (`order by rn desc`)

It should be OK for as many words as you want, if they are separated by a single space (otherwise, you'll first have to make sure that there's only one space).

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you still want to show the name in one column but show firstname lastname instead of lastname firstname. Here is one way

```
select 
substr(name,instr(name,' ')+1)||' '||substr(name,1,instr(name,' ') -1) as fullname
from  your_table;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this function , I use this :

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTR(name_column,5,9),CONCAT(' ',SUBSTR(name_column,1,4))) FROM 
TABLE_NAME;
```

Example :

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTR('Dan Brown',5,9),CONCAT(' ',SUBSTR('Dan Brown',1,4))) FROM DUAL;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYEJY.png)

Or if you have name or title different column then you can also use this :
*select regexp_substr(name, '[^ ]+', 1, 1) as first_name,
       regexp_substr(name, '[^ ]+', 1, 2) as second_name*

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Post it as text (as you've already done), [using markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).